# DropdownButtonFormField Reset after submit a form in Flutter

Tags: flutter, forms, submit, reset, dropdownbutton

How to reset a DropdownButtonFormField value to default value or reset DropdownButtonFormField after submitting a form.

Comment: Please add your code so we can see what your working with

Answer (score 1):

you can do so using a GlobalKey like:

```
   GlobalKey<FormFieldState> newKey =  GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
```

and assign it to your DropdownButtonFormField like:

```
   DropdownButtonFormField(
      key: newKey,
    )
```

and when you want to reset it you call :

```
   newKey.currentState.reset();
```

Comment: Great solution. You should just initialize your `newKey` variable in order to work.

Comment: thanks for the notify, I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this to Tareq's answer. To reset the whole form you could use `GlobalKey<Form>` , but to reset the elements of the form only you must assign each of them a `GlobalKey<FormFieldState>`.

Try out this code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _cityDropdownButtonKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
  List<String> cities = ["Paris", "New york", "Yaoundé"];
  String cityValue = "Paris";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Reset DropDownButton Field"),
        ),
        body: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                  key: _cityDropdownButtonKey,
                  value: cityValue,
                  items: cities
                      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                        (e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                          value: e,
                          child: Text(e),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                  onChanged: (String? newValue) {//Any code},
                ),
                TextFormField(),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    //Call this to reset the field
                    _cityDropdownButtonKey.currentState!.reset();
                  },
                  child: const Text('Reset the Button Only'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                   //call this to reset the form
                    _formKey.currentState!.reset();
                  },
                  child: const Text('Reset the whole form'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Make you GlobalKeys static if you want to reset from another page.